# How to get enum value from property

Tags: java, enumeration

I have an enum with values `VALID` and `INVALID`, which have a boolean property associated with them. I would like to get the enum value based on a boolean value I provide.

If it is `true` I should get `VALID`, if it is `false` I should get `INVALID`. I would like to do so in a getter method like the below, based on the value of the member variable

```
public boolean getCardValidityStatus() {
    return CardValidationStatus status = CardValidationStatus(this.mCardValidityStatus));
}
```

My code:

```
private enum CardValidationStatus {
    VALID(true),
    INVALID(false);

    private boolean isValid;
    CardValidationStatus(boolean isValid) {
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }
    public boolean getValidityStatus() {
        return this.isValid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're able to achieve that using a static lookup method in the enum itself:

```
private enum CardValidationStatus {
    VALID(true),
    INVALID(false);

    //...

    public static CardValidationStatus forBoolean(boolean status) {

        //this is simplistic given that it's a boolean-based lookup
        //but it can get complex, such as using a loop...
        return status ? VALID : INVALID; 
    }
}
```

And the appropriate status can be retrieved using:

```
public CardValidationStatus getCardValidityStatus() {
    return CardValidationStatus.forBoolean(this.mCardValidityStatus));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `parse` method to your enum, which takes the `boolean`, iterates over all the values and returns the one that matches, for example:

```
public CardValidationStatus parse(boolean isValid) {
    for (CardValidationStatus cardValidationStatus : CardValidationStatus.values()) {
        if (cardValidationStatus.getValidityStatus() == isValid) {
            return cardValidationStatus;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: For your case, ernest_k's answer is probably better, but I've included this an example of the same thing if you had something other than a boolean value.

Answer (score -1):

#### @ernest_k solution made this work, but I think that's not reliable solution.

You should always do code which is independent.

- Because his solution is hardcoded. What if values of `VALID` & `INVALID` are changed. Will you change your `forBoolean` logics also?
- Because he did not check what the Enum fields are holding inside it.

Reliable solution will be @DaveyDaveDave answer. This will also work when you have many status with VALID & INVAlID.

```
private enum CardValidationStatus {
    VALID(true),
    INVALID(false);

    //...

    public CardValidationStatus forBoolean(boolean isValid) {
        for (CardValidationStatus cardValidationStatus : CardValidationStatus.values()) {
            if (cardValidationStatus.getValidityStatus() == isValid) {
                return cardValidationStatus;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

#### Suggestion (Easiest way I think)

Why are you making Enum just for storing 2 boolean values?

Just make static boolean named by `VALID` & `INVALID`.

```
public static final boolean CARD_STATUS_VALID = true;
public static final boolean CARD_STATUS_INVALID = false;

if(cardStatus == CARD_STATUS_VALID){
 // todo
}
```